# fs.promise.rm can not create promise before file is created

Tags: javascript, promise, fs

I try to create a `fs.promise.writeFile` operation and the `fs.promise.rm` operation for the same file and execute them in a later stage. I get the error `ENOENT: no such file or directory`. I was trying something like (for simplicity and reproducibility I reversed the order of the created promises in this example):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function test() {
    try {
        let file = path.resolve('test.txt');
        const rm = fs.promises.rm(file);
        const writeFile = fs.promises.writeFile(file, 'foo');
        await writeFile;
        await rm;
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

So it seems to me that this operation throws before actually being executed. Is there anything I can do to prevent the premature partial execution of the `rm` operation?

Comment: Well, actually the error says it all: You are trying to delete the file before you created it ... You probably think a promise "starts executing" only once you `await` it. That's not the case ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this in the wrong order. The promise can start completing before the await call. You should do `await writeFile` before `const rm =`.